# How can you merge accounts when you've not got access to old email?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, users, merge-accounts

I have this old account and I can't log in to the email associated with it anymore:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/847047/avenas8808

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/171485/avenas8808

How can I merge this account with the old one, keeping all post history, etc. and points from the old one with the new account?

The old account wasn't blocked, had higher reputation, but I changed the email from a Mailinator account, then to a webmail, but I can't access it anymore; I forgot the password/backup email to that one.

I don't have any question blocks or bans on that account. I can't log in to post *merge me* on that account.

Comment: Use the contact form at the bottom of every page and select: "I need to merge user profiles"